# YADCF date_range filter with bootstrap-datetimepicker not displaying correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-datetimepicker, yadcf

I am using `jquery-datatables-rails` and the `YADCF` plugin in my rails app, and I would like to use the `date_range` filter type with the `bootstrap-datetimepicker` option, as I am using it elsewhere in the app. However, when I use those options for a column:

```
{ column_number: 3, filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_type: 'range_date', datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker', date_format: 'M/D/YYYY' }
```

the widget does not display correctly, it looks like this:

[image: bootstrap-datetimepicker displaying incorrectly]

What can I do to make this display correctly? Here is what it looks like elsewhere in my app, which is how I want it to look:

[image: bootstrap-datetimepicker correct]

with the exception that I do not want the time to be selectable in this case, only the date.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here, hopefully this helps someone else trying to use jquery datatables and bootstrap-datetimepicker together - https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/958

From that source:

```
// Fix interference between jquery datatables and bootstrap datetimepicker
table.dataTable.table-condensed .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget thead > tr > th {
    padding-right: 0;
 }
table.dataTable.table .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget thead > tr > th {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```